# The simplest and most concise way to delete a row?

Tags: abap, internal-tables

Is there any simplest/fastest way for below code:

```
DATA:   lv_knuma_ag  LIKE STANDARD TABLE OF zta_fg_hdr WITH HEADER LINE.
RANGES: lr_knuma_ag  FOR  zta_fg_hdr-knuma_ag.

"Select `knuma_ag` and save it to internal table `lv_knuma_ag`
LOOP AT li_promo.
  SELECT dest~knuma_ag
    FROM zta_fg_dest AS dest
    INNER JOIN zta_s_d_xkunnr AS xkunnr ON xkunnr~zcd_dest EQ dest~zcd_dest
    APPENDING CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE lv_knuma_ag
    WHERE dest~knuma_ag EQ li_promo-knuma_ag
          AND xkunnr~xkunnr EQ gi_vl-vkbur.
ENDLOOP.

"Insert `lv_knuma_ag` onto ranges table `lr_knuma_ag`
LOOP AT lv_knuma_ag.
  lr_knuma_ag-sign   = 'I'.
  lr_knuma_ag-option = 'EQ'.
  lr_knuma_ag-low    = lv_knuma_ag-knuma_ag.
  lr_knuma_ag-high   = space.
  APPEND lr_knuma_ag.
ENDLOOP.

"Delete row in `li_promo` where `knuma_ag` is in ranges table `lr_knuma_ag`
IF NOT lr_knuma_ag IS INITIAL.
  DELETE li_promo WHERE knuma_ag IN lr_knuma_ag.
ENDIF.
```

As you see on the code, it contains twice loop to only fill the ranges table. I would like to make it only one, is it possible? Thanks.

Comment: So you want to select rows from `ZTA_FG_DEST` where the `KNUMA_AG` is in both `LI_PROMO` and `LV_KNUMA_AG`?

Comment: @vwegert: No, I would like to delete row in `li_promo` where the `knuma_ag` is in `zta_fg_dest`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it should be possible to achieve this without flooding your DBMS with possibly thousands of queries:

```
DATA: lt_knuma_ag_hash TYPE HASHED TABLE OF insert_type_of_knuma_ag_here WITH UNIQUE KEY TABLE_table_line.

IF li_promo[] IS NOT INITIAL.
  SELECT DISTINCT knuma_ag
    FROM zta_fg_dest
    INTO TABLE lt_knuma_ag_hash
    FOR ALL ENTRIES IN li_promo
    WHERE knuma_ag = li_promo-knuma_ag.
ENDIF.

LOOP AT li_promo ASSIGNING <li_promo>.
  READ TABLE lt_knuma_ag_hash TRANSPORTING NO FIELDS WITH TABLE KEY table_line = <li_promo>-knuma_ag.
  IF sy-subrc = 0.
    DELETE li_promo.
  ENDIF.
ENDLOOP.
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the code. But, what is `lv_knuma_ag` for in your code? Please see the update above..